# Page load time statistic

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 6 & trying to track page load time statistics (starting from 1st async call / DOM rendering to end of last async call / DOM rendering). Is there any way from Angular prospective to achieve this?

I tried with process.timing though, but seems it is not giving correct load time. Any idea how to track this total page load time?

Comment: Doesn't developer tools help?

Comment: actually I need that loading time for reporting / statistic purpose, so need to save in database.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to get the current Date before loading any other script and get the current Date once again when the angular app hits the run phase. If you subtract both dates you will get the loading time.

What I mean is something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var start = Date.now();
</script>
```

And then, when you implement the controller logic add something like that:

```
run(function($window) {
    result = Date.now() - $window.start);
    console.log(result); 
});
```

Comment: what would be the correct life cycle / phase for Angular 6?

Comment: The life cycle phases (also called hooks) in Angular are:
constructor
ngOnChanges
ngOnInit
ngDoCheck
-> ngAfterContentInit
-> ngAgterContentChecked
-> ngAfterViewInit
->ngAfterViewChecked
ngOnDestroy

More info: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks


Something like this should do the job.
angular.module('app', []).
    config(function() {
        // some code
    }).
    run(function($window) {
        result = Date.now() - $window.start);
        console.log(result); 
    });

Comment: I believe "ngAfterViewChecked" life cycle hook is one we can consider, but the problem is it gets called so many times and I have no clue in which call the whole page load was completed!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would be to use [APP_INITIALIZER](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-how-to-use-app-initializer/) to initialise a global time variable

The best practice would be to put your end timing logic in **ngAfterViewInit** and put no business logic in **ngAfterViewChecked**

ngAfterViewChecked() would be invoked everytime the DOM tree gets any change. This is by design.

Use ngAfterViewInit to get the time difference and reinitialize the global variable

Comment: I think, by the time life cycle hook "ngAfterViewInit" runs; we cannot say all the server calls are completed!

Comment: @Ratikant yes that is true, and obvious that you need to check for time when all server calls are done.